# WYSIWYG with possibility of uploading images form client's disc

Tags: php, image-manipulation, wysiwyg

It would be great if I could upload an image from my hard drive using wysiwig HTML editor on my website. Editors like FCKeditor or CKeditor provide this option but images can be upload only to one folder whitch needs to be specify in 'someconfig' file. 
I need wysiwig editor where I could dynamicly create string with 'uploadFolderPath' while implementing eg. in php code.

something like:

```
$editor -> new Editor();
$editor -> uploadFolderPath = "blabla/blabla/";
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I am using Tinymce editor with tinybrowser plugin for upload/manage imges and  videos. I have modified its configuration file so that I can set current upload folder in session. Also I can have different upload locations for different instances of editor in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent Javascript image/media manager called [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/), which works very well with CKEditor, and according to [this documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/CKEditor_Integration) it looks like its directory can be configured at runtime.

The only drawback is that this software is not free, although you can use the unlicensed version which has a banner.

Comment: I'm looking for some free version with no banners.. Although I will definitely check out this manager. Thank you.